# dropDatabase from spring mongo

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I would like to dropDatabase in my mongo before my integration tests. Is it possible to do this through spring mongo ?

If it's not available for now, is it possible on fetching the com.mongodb.DB object somehow from spring mongo, so i can invoke it's dropDatabase() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly cleaner solution which I am using is to use the MongoDbFactory object, as below:

```
mongoDbFactory.getDb().dropDatabase();
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722566/spring-mongo-nested-inner-query

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone needs the info, notice that since 3.0 there is no dropDatabase() method in the MongoDatabase api, so you have to write this instead:

`mongoTemplate.getDb().drop();`

[>> source <<](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MongoDatabase.html)

Answer (score 1):

Found it at last !

From mongodb shell :

```
> db.dropDatabase
function () {
    if (arguments.length) {
        throw "dropDatabase doesn't take arguments";
    }
    return this._dbCommand({dropDatabase:1});
}
```

combined with [mongoOperations' executeCommand](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#executeCommand%28java.lang.String%29) :

```
@Autowired private MongoOperations ops;

@BeforeMethod
public void dropDb() {
    this.ops.executeCommand("{dropDatabase:1}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

mongoTemplate.getDb().dropDatabase();