# Spring Mongo nested inner query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-mongodb

Trying to update an inner array document. There are three levels of the nested array. I am able to remove till the second level but not able to update the third level

```
       {  
   "id":"Test",
   "name":"Test",
    "sections":[  
   {  
      "sectionname":"Example1",
      "sectionroles":["test1", "test2", "test3"],
      "subcategory":[  
         {  
            "Value":"demo",
            "ValueId":"123333333333",
           "sectionroles":["test1", "test2", "test3"],
         },
         {  
            "Value":"Example2",
            "Value":"6577544333333",
            "sectionroles":["test1", "test2", "test3"],

         }
      ]
       }
```

I am able to remove   the sections through the section name but not able to remove the subcategory.

```
     Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("name").is("Test"));
      query.fields().elemMatch("sections", 
       Criteria.where("sectionname").is("Example1"));
      Update update = new Update();
       update.pull("sections", new BasicDBObject("sectionname", 
       "Example1"));
       mongotemplate.updateMulti(query, update, "menu");
```

What do I add in the existing Criteria to remove or add any value in a subcategory   ???